# Why this syntax works?

Tags: php, database, syntax

I tried to list all of my databases so I have used this:

```
$sql="SHOW DATABASES"; 
    $query=mysql_query($sql,$connect);
```

then I fetch the db into an array, and I also listed the tables of each db from this array:

```
 while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)){
$sql3="SHOW TABLES FROM `".$row['Database']."`"; //**i dont understand why $row['Database'] works?**
$query3=mysql_query($sql3, $connect);
}
```

Let's give an example array(db1,db2,db3). When I use:

```
SHOW TABLES FROM `".$row['Database'].
```

it will show each table from:

```
$row[0](db1) , $row[1](db2) , $row[2](db3)
```

Am I right? This is the theory behind this syntax? Or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are accessing the array result by index name, if you make a `print_r` of the variable $row you will get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Database] => information_schema
)
Array
(
    [Database] => mysql
)
```

So you can access the value by using `Database` index

EDITED:

In case of tables you will get something like this:

```
Array
(
    [Tables_in_information_schema] => CHARACTER_SETS
)
...
Array
(
    [Tables_in_mysql] => columns_priv
)
```

So the the index will change with every table, you can access it with something like this:

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($query3)){
    echo $row2["Tables_in_{$row['Database']}"];
}
```

OR

You can use `mysql_fetch_row` instead, an access it using position:

```
while ($row2 = mysql_fetch_row($query3)){
    echo $row2[0];
}
```

**IMPORTANT:**

I forgot to mention, but **mysql_** extension is deprecated so you should use PDO or **mysqli_** functions instead

Comment: so database is an index? something like a reserved word? if i want to do the same thing for tables,lets say if i am fetching tables and assign them to $row1 , can i use something like $row['tables'] ??

Comment: for tables i did a different thing,i fetch every table in an array,then i used a foreach to go through array

Comment: thanks a lot,now everything its in order inside my mind.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the language you are using. But database queries typically return a resultsets, that allow you do access the values from different columns either by the index of the column or by it's name. The later is what you are doing here.